# What's more efficient: string searches, or joins through SQL?

Tags: sql, string, function, search, optimization

I have two lists of words and I need to find matches (intersection of the two sets.)
Should I store each list as a string and find matches through string functions (like a regular expression) or store the words in a table, and have SQL find matches by joining?

Comment: Well you can Try it and see Which one is faster. also, MySQL, Sql-Server, Oracle.. ?

Comment: Whitout trying, I think it would be faster storing in a table and do some Joins, because the Motor is optimized to manage rows/Fields and Joins, and it will do more faster than using String functions to compare two strings. But, again, test it

Comment: MySQL, but I'm not tied to it. I'm assuming most databases have similar speeds when it comes to simple joins. I'm trying to figure out if one approach is, for example, a magnitude faster than another one

Comment: Is using a hashtable an option? You could store one list in a hashtable and search for the other list's items.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost impossible to say without more information about the problem.  Here are some things to consider:

- How many different distinct items do you have?
- How many different combinations would be on a typical row?
- Do your searches require looking for wildcards?
- How long are the individual items?
- Specifics on the database engine and hardware you are running on.

I want to emphasize that in almost all situations, you want to store the values in another table.  Performance is not necessarily the primary reason.  More important are ease of updating and deleting individual values, and the ability to support many more types of queries (such as a list of all available values).

But, we can still think about the performance issues.  Storing values in a single string simply requires fetching the page with the record on it, and then applying a function that goes through the string.  For simple patterns (such as identifying the presence of a fixed substring), this should go quite fast.  There are few things that computers do faster than looping through strings and comparing values (assuming a reasonable implementation).

In the fastest possible join, both tables need to be read in, and the keys need to be matched.  This requires additional effort.  The situation is even worse, because you really want two additional tables, one for the individual string items and the other for the relationship between the original records and the items.

At this point, you may think "gosh, strings seem like a better idea".  This is wrong.  One of the big differences is in average size.  If you items are, on average, longer than, say, 4 characters, then you save space by using a reference table.  This saved space immediately translates into improved performance, because there is less I/O.  With indexes, the additional tables would be in memory anyway, so the matching would be quite fast.

And, there is the issue of querying.  You can use standard SQL functions for queries such as records that have A and B (many string functions are database specific).  You can easily find out exactly which items are in the database, and relatively easily find what pairs exist on records.  You can keep track of when an item is added to a record, and the first time it appears in the database.  Generally, this flexible functionality -- which is just basic SQL functionality -- is what you need when managing this type of data.

Comment: I should have specified my needs better, sorry. I have a list of countries that each user has visited. I then want to find out which countries have users A and B both visited.

Comment: In this case, you should absolutely use a separate table of countries and user-countries.  The first would have one row per country (along with information about them).  The second would have a row for each user and each country, probably also with the date that the user visited the country.

Answer (score 0):

Storing in a table will be much faster than a SQL string manipulation function in most circumstances especially if you can index the words.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking if this:

```
SELECT word FROM table_one WHERE word in (SELECT word FROM table_two)
```

is faster than this:

```
SELECT table_one.word FROM table_one 
INNER JOIN table_two ON table_one.word = table_two.word
```

The first answer should be faster, because the second creates a (potentially large) temporary object (the joined table).

Note that I assume you have an index on `word`. Also: if the strings are very long (URLs, for example), this will be very slow, and you should match on a hash instead.

Comment: That's actually a question I haven't considered. I was thinking SQL join like you mentioned versus using a string functions in a programming language.